# ELF format: is ELF a subset of .o/.so or is ELF basically the entire .o/.so?

Tags: linux, elf

I'm currently doing some study on ELF format. I would like to confirm something I think is right.

ELF is a format, it stands for Executable and linkable format. In linux, everything is in ELF format.

When using gcc to compile a code with -c and -fPIC file, it transfers the code into a .o file with ELF format.

Is it correct if I say .o/.so and linux executables are ELF files? or is ELF something inside a .o/.so file? In other words, is ELF a subset of .o/.so or is ELF basically the entire .o/.so?

I would like to confirm this, because I'd like to make sure I understand this. Sorry for asking a stupid question.

Comment: The title is how you sell your question. In this way, it is difficult to get good answer

Comment: @CharlieFish by the way, why this doesn't belong to SO?

Comment: @Amadeus I have no idea how in the would this has anything to do with programming. MAYBE the UNIX Linux Stack Exchange site. Maybe....

Comment: @Amadeus I guess maybe it does on certain levels. I think it's at the very least a bit of a stretch. Definitely your point about the title is a good one.

Comment: I guess code generation belongs to SO and how you layout it, I guess too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it correct if I say .o/.so and linux executables are ELF files? or is ELF something inside a .o/.so file? In other words, is ELF a subset of .o/.so or is ELF basically the entire .o/.so?

Yes. Object files (`.o`), shared libraries (`.so`), and executables (`.exe`) are three of the four types of ELF files. (The fourth type is core files -- a dump of the state of a crashed process, sometimes used for post-mortem debugging.)

All four types use the same general format, but will have some differences specific to their type. For instance, an executable will typically have an entry point, whereas object files and shared libraries won't.